# JSON response from spring boot rest controller getting repeated

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I was trying to build a rest api using Spring boot 1.5.9.RELEASE and been stuck on this issue. **The post request to api end points works just fine** but when comes to **get requests the result gets repeated**. The response which the app produces for get request is

```
{"data":["Administrator"]}{"data":["Administrator"]}
```

The associated request mapping class code

```
@RequestMapping("/get")
    public ResponseEntity getAllRoles()throws Exception{

        List<Roles> roles = rolesService.getRoles();
        Set<String> roleNames = new HashSet<>();
        for(Roles r : roles)
            roleNames.add(r.getRoleName());
        return new ResponseEntity(new Response(roleNames), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

The Response class

```
public class Response<T> {

    private T data;

    public Response() {}

    public Response(T data) {
            this.data = data;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Any ideas about how to solve the issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you debugged your code and made sure that the List or the HashSet doesn't contain two objects instead of one?

Comment: Additionally can you inspect the value of new ResponseEntity and post that?  I realzie you cant populate the set twice, so I think you're doing something very odd at the end.  Why do you not explicitly state the type of your response entity?  Also, no need to loop, just try this    Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>(service.getRoles());

Comment: convert the hashset to list. so this.data = new ArrayList<String>(data);. Let me know if that works

Comment: `/get` is a very interesting choice for an endpoint.  Just for giggles, change it to something else and change `@RequestMapping` to `@GetMapping`

Answer (score 1):

You are creating response twice, use below

```
RequestMapping("/get")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAllRoles()throws Exception{

        List<Roles> roles = rolesService.getRoles();
        Set<String> roleNames = new HashSet<>();
        for(Roles r : roles)
            roleNames.add(r.getRoleName());
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(roleNames, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Injecting @JsonProperty("yourFiledName") at the getter method works for me.
`
public class Response {

```
private T data;

public Response() {}

public Response(T data) {
        this.data = data;
}

@JsonProperty("data")
public T getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(T data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

}
`